# How to break a concave polyhedron into a few convex polyhedron?

Tags: convex-polytopes

I would like to know is there a way to break a concave polyhedron into a few convex polyhedron?

Comment: In certain cases yes, In general, I don't know. Could you please provide some evidence/illustration that you've thought about this, and some indication of why you want to know? Otherwise the way you phrase the question makes it sound like idle curiosity

Comment: What have you tried so far to attack this problem?  Have you tried to break down a concave polygon into its component convex polygons?  How are you specifying the polyhedron...  

Comment: Just the fact that it can be broken down (triangulated) is not as obvious as it seems at first glance. This seems to me to be roughly equivalent to the Jordan curve theorem, so I'd beware any answer that is both simple and doesn't use Jordan's result. And then there's that pesky adjective you used: "few". Nice problem.

Comment: It may be a nice problem, but I still wish the original post had communicated more than "here's something I don't know, let me know when you guys have the answer"

Answer (score 11):

The problem of partitioning a polyhedron into the minimum possible number of convex pieces is NP-hard.
Bernard Chazelle established a quadratic lower bound—$\Omega(n^2)$ in terms of the
number $n$ of vertices—in the paper
"Convex partitions of polyhedra: a lower bound and worst-case optimal algorithm,"
[*SIAM Journal on Computing*
Volume 13 ,  Issue 3  (August 1984)
pp. 488 - 507](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1172).
He also provided a theoretical algorithm in that paper, perhaps never implemented.
There has been subsequent work, e.g., 
"Strategies for polyhedral surface decomposition: An experimental study,"
[*Computational Geometry*,
Volume 7, Issues 5-6, April 1997, Pages 327-342](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6TYS-3SNV32D-4&_user=10&_coverDate=04%252F30%252F1997&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=search&_origin=search&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_searchStrId=1491956375&_rerunOrigin=scholar.google&_acct=C000050221&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=10&md5=ecb66566d22693e442293764cd00b6cc&searchtype=a).

Comment: The link to `sciencedirect.com` is broken, but the article can be found at [doi:10.1016/S0925-7721(96)00024-7](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0925-7721(96)00024-7) ([Zbl 1133.52305](https://zbmath.org/1133.52305)).

Answer (score 6):

Take all planes of the facets of your polyhedron $P$. They divide the space onto (open) convex regions. Each of them either is contained in $P$, or does not have common points with $P$. Take those regions which are contained in $P$ (or their closures, if you prefer).

Comment: I don't think it's obvious that the intersection of a convex set with the nonconvex polyhedron is itself convex.

Comment: @Kevin
It is either empty or itself, hence convex

Comment: Fedor, I just drew a nonconvex polygon P in the plane, attempting to cause one of your convex sets C to be part inside and part outside the  original P. It was easy, I count 14 edges, with C a certain triangle. Putting in a malicious bend at the right place, making 15 edges, the intersection of C with P is not convex either. Anyway, the number of edges is nearly irrelevant, as I forced the bad intersection first, then filled in the rest. P resembles a capital letter C with teeth.

Comment: The way I understood Fedor's suggestion is to form the _arrangement_ determined by all the planes containing faces of the polyhedron. Each cell of the arrangement is convex, and is either inside or outside
the polyhedron.  Here the term "arrangement" is defined at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrangement_of_planes .

Comment: @Joseph yes, that's my point exactly
sorry for being not clear

Comment: Note that an arrangement of $n$ planes divides space into $\Theta(n^3)$ cells.

Comment: Wikipedia does not mention the word "cell." It would appear that you are demanding that the cells be minimal under intersection, i.e. if a convex set is given by an intersection of a few of your half-spaces, but is then disconnected by another hyperplane in the arrangement, it then is not called a "cell." 
$$ $$
They do mention regions or chambers.

Comment: @Will: Wikipedia now mentions the word "cell"! :-)  Your definition of the term is exactly correct.

Comment: Joseph, good. Evidently simply correctly identifying all the cells must be a difficult enough problem on a computer in general. 

Comment: @Will: Yes. Even in 2D it is a difficult computational problem to identify all the cells in an arrangement of lines.